Is There Suppose to be a Gap between the Driver Side CV Axle and Differential? - 2003 Hummer H2

This gap is 3/4 of an inch.
Before I got to work on the steering components of the vehicle, when driving it, I would hear a pop/thump when turning and speeding up that usually sounded more than once in a turn. Almost all if not all the sounds come from the driver side either right next to the wheel or closer to the middle of the vehicle.
According to the mechanic I took it to, he said the cv axle seems completely fine and that the sound is likely coming from the worn out ball joints. I have found that the upper ball joints are indeed completely worn.
Another thing is that I found when taking off the tires and loosening the axle nuts is that the driver side axle was not tight, Apparently I did not tighten the nut according to torque specs when I replaced the hub assembly back in 2021. I thought this loose nut may be what was causing the sounds until I discovered the gap between the cv axle and differential.
Back to my main question, is there supposed to be a gap like this here?

Yes. As you can see in this image I copied from eBay, there is supposed to be a gap there:

